# How to use a % wild card in a query to an sqlite3 table with user input where clause

Tags: wildcard

I have written a query which allows a user to search a table in an sqlite3 database with any of 4 different fields.  It will only return data if what the user enters is an exact match is there a way to put a wild card in for each field. Code below

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("lucyartists.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Get user input
print ('Search for an Artist')
print ('You can search by Name, DOB, Movement or Description')
print ('')
name = input("Enter Artists Name: ")
dob = input("Enter Date of Birth: ")
movement = input("Enter Movemment: ")
description = input ("Enter Description: ")
#query database with user input
sql = ("select name, dob, movement, description from artists where name like (?) or dob like (?) or movement like (?) or description like (?)")
values = (name, dob, movement, description)
#Run query
cursor.execute(sql, values)
result = cursor.fetchall()
#print results without quotes and comma separated
print()
print('RESULTS')
for r in result:
print()
print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]))
```